# How to set symbols and colors to distinguish data in an R plot?

Tags: r, plot

I try to create the following plot in R, based on the dataframe bellow. What I find tricky is to set the symbols and colors by gender, and also writing the legend correctly. Could somebody give me a hand, specially regarding the syntax of the code? Many thanks in advance.

```
plot(students$height, students$shoesize, xlab="Height", ylab="Shoesize")
```

[image]

Dataframe:

```
> students
   height shoesize gender population
1     181       44   male     kuopio
2     160       38 female     kuopio
3     174       42 female     kuopio
4     170       43   male     kuopio
5     172       43   male     kuopio
6     165       39 female     kuopio
7     161       38 female     kuopio
8     167       38 female    tampere
9     164       39 female    tampere
10    166       38 female    tampere
11    162       37 female    tampere
12    158       36 female    tampere
13    175       42   male    tampere
14    181       44   male    tampere
15    180       43   male    tampere
16    177       43   male    tampere
17    173       41   male    tampere
```

Comment: What plot statement are you using now?

Comment: This is what I have until now: ```> plot(students$height, students$shoesize, xlab="Height", ylab="Shoesize")```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I have added your code in the comment to the question. When someone asks further explanations, **please don't post code as comments, edit the question instead.** Upvote, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not good with colors. What color do you think the females are? Everything else should roughly fit:

```
students <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="   height shoesize gender population
1     181       44   male     kuopio
2     160       38 female     kuopio
3     174       42 female     kuopio
4     170       43   male     kuopio
5     172       43   male     kuopio
6     165       39 female     kuopio
7     161       38 female     kuopio
8     167       38 female    tampere
9     164       39 female    tampere
10    166       38 female    tampere
11    162       37 female    tampere
12    158       36 female    tampere
13    175       42   male    tampere
14    181       44   male    tampere
15    180       43   male    tampere
16    177       43   male    tampere
17    173       41   male    tampere",
                       stringsAsFactors = TRUE)


plot(students$height, students$shoesize, xlab="Height", ylab="Shoesize",
     col = c("violet", "blue")[as.numeric(students$gender)], 
     pch = c(4, 1)[as.numeric(students$gender)])
legend("bottomright", col = c("violet", "blue"), pch = c(4,1), legend = c("female", "male"))
```

[image]

Comment: ¡Many thanks! I'd say that the gender "female" is represented in magenta on the example plot. Now I will dig into why the 'as.numeric' function there, and why the colors are written in that order (alphabetical order of the gender values, maybe?).

Comment: `as.numeric` only makes sense because 'gender' is of type factor. See that `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` in `read.table`? That is essential here. As for the order: In the `plot` part it follows the rules of factors, in the `legend` part you are free to do whatever you want. Be carefull though, compared to `ggplot2` it is far easier to make legends that are plain wrong!  I encourage you to learn base graphics thoroughly, but once you 'got it', definitely invest some time and effort in order to learn `ggplot2`, too. Both are great, each in it's own way and sort.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a `ggplot2` approach:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
df <- structure(list(height = c(181L, 160L, 174L, 170L, 172L, 165L, 
161L, 167L, 164L, 166L, 162L, 158L, 175L, 181L, 180L, 177L, 173L
), shoesize = c(44L, 38L, 42L, 43L, 43L, 39L, 38L, 38L, 39L, 
38L, 37L, 36L, 42L, 44L, 43L, 43L, 41L), gender = c("male", "female", 
"female", "male", "male", "female", "female", "female", "female", 
"female", "female", "female", "male", "male", "male", "male", 
"male"), population = c("kuopio", "kuopio", "kuopio", "kuopio", 
"kuopio", "kuopio", "kuopio", "tampere", "tampere", "tampere", 
"tampere", "tampere", "tampere", "tampere", "tampere", "tampere", 
"tampere")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17"))
```

The code:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=height,y=shoesize,shape=gender,color=gender))+
  geom_point(size=3)+theme_bw()
```

Output:

[image]

If you want go further, you can modify the shapes and colors with `scale_shape_manual()` and `scale_color_manual()`.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=height,y=shoesize,shape=gender,color=gender))+
  geom_point(size=3)+theme_bw()+
  scale_color_manual(values = c('male'='blue','female'='purple'))+
  scale_shape_manual(values = c('male'=3,'female'=4))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. I try not to install R packages before I get the basics, but I'll dig into it.

Comment: @Kai7 `ggplot2` has plenty of options you can use and that are easy to implement!

Comment: Yes, so has matplotlib and many others. Even base graphics have many options. They were good for decades and many packages use them as standard. Their impementations tend to be stable. I get it, that you like that package but there is no need to use it if the question was explicitely to use something else.